# Android Junit4 tests are not showing up in CircleCI Test Summary

Tags: android, circleci

I have an Android project that runs on CircleCI. The tests run succesfully, and I can upload the like this in my config.yml file:

```
  - store_artifacts:
      path: module1/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/
      destination: test-results/module1
  - store_artifacts:
      path: module2/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/
      destination: test-results/module2
  - store_test_results:
      path: test-results
```

These are uploaded successfully to the Artifacts tab on CircleCI. In the Artifacts tab I can open each module and click on the test report of each individual module. I get a nice Index.html file that presents the summary for that module.

However I am unable to get the Test Summary to work. It just says "Set Up Test Summary" no matter how I change my folder structure.

This is problematic because if a test fails I have to open each module individually and see those reports instead of getting a full summary.

Are Android test reports generated by Gradle 5.2.1 like mine not supported by CircleCI, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that Android/Kotlin does not necessarily generate XML reports by default.

The solution is to put the following in each of your module build.gradle file:

```
android {

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            reports {
                junitXml.enabled = true
                junitXml.destination = file("$buildDir/../../build/test-results/moduleName")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then update your config.yml file's path to:

```
  - store_artifacts:
      path: build/test-results
      destination: test-results
  - store_test_results:
      path: build/test-results
```